# private is not blocking calls to function in module (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, private

```
module Test
  private
  def secret
    puts '<>'
  end
end

include Test

secret #it works
Test.secret #it fails: "private method `secret' called for Test:Module (NoMethodError)"
```

Is there some design reason why private works this way? I am aware that I can use

```
      private_class_method :secret
```

to block also the first call but I want to know whatever there is some use case for private in modules.

Comment: You can call a class's private methods from within that class, including private methods added by included modules.  That's the semantics of `private` in Ruby.  You can never call private methods with an explicit receiver, even within the class containing the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generally good way to start understanding what a private method is in Ruby is to think of it as a method that can only be called implicitly. That means that the object that is receiving the method shouldn't be explicitly specified:

```
my_private_method       # Implicit call, this is OK.
self.my_private_method  # Explicit call, this won't work.
```

Using this simple approach you can ensure (somewhat) that private methods won't be callable on objects other than `self`. For example:

```
my_private_method                # Calling private method on self, this is OK.
other_object.its_private_method  # Calling other object's private method, this won't work.
```

Now, when you have a module that defines a private method you first need to include it somewhere in order to be able to use the method. What you did in you example is include the module at the topmost level. When you do that Ruby includes the module in the [`Object` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html). That means that your `secret` method is now a private method of all Ruby objects, and since all Ruby objects will have the private `secret` method, you can **implicitly** call it from anywhere in your program now:

```
secret         #=> "<>"
class MyClass
  secret
end            #=> "<>"
```

To give you an idea, your `secret` method will behave pretty much like the `puts` method does (also one of `Object`'s private methods). You can't call `puts` explicitly on an object, but you can use it anywhere in your program. And that is *one* of the reasons you could want to have private methods in a module.

Another reason could be to implement methods only the including module or class is meant to use, for example:

```
module M
  private
  def my_private_method
    "This is private."
  end
end

class C
  include M
  def my_public_method
    "<#{my_private_method}>"
  end
end

c = C.new
c.my_public_method   #=> "<This is private.>"
c.my_private_method  #=> This won't work.
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, you're including the module in the class **you're currently in**. And you're running methods from the class **you're currently in**.

So it works - like it should.

```
class CA
  include Test
end

CA.new.secret # THIS shouldn't work

include Test
secret # THIS should
```